# Show only client-side validation with client and server validators in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have something like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox id="test" runat="sever"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="test"  
ErrorMessage="Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
```

if in the code behind, I set the label to "You must enter a value if the textbox is empty" to validate it on the server side and this is fine, but if javascript is enabled, I don't want to show the client side validation and the server side label together.  Is this something where I would just have to disable the client-side validators if javascript was enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can just use a single validator and accomplish both client and server validation. ASP.Net will take care of determining whether or not to fire client only or client and server with only a little help from you. You should never rely on client validation alone, but the server validation can be silent, i.e. you don't need to have two error messages coming back to the user.

Therefore, you don't need your own status label, and you will need to add a check to the event handler(s) that are fired from your page.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. :)

Well, I am not sure that I understand your question, because it seems that you have answered it yourself. Can't you just disable client side validation for this RequiredFieldValidator to achieve what you want?

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="test"
    ErrorMessage="Required" EnableClientScript="False"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I got the question, but you can perform a validation in your javascript code and avoid a PostBack.

```
var doSomething = function(sender, args){
 if(Page_IsValid){
  //Do something cool
  return true;
 }else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

I was facing some similar issue today at work, please refer to the following link, it's very useful

ASP.NET Valildation In Depth
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx